# how to work with json correctly in python

Tags: python, json

I've started to learn about using json in python.

Python version :  2.7.17 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04

I wrote the code :

```
import json

database = '/home/username/dev/python/p17.json'
counter = 1
write = True

with open(database,'w') as db:
    while write:
        name = raw_input("Please enter name :")
        if name == 'q':
            write = False
            continue
        dict = {"counter":counter,"name":name,"foods":["toilet paper","pizza"]}
        json.dump(dict,db)
        counter +=1


with open(database) as db:
    dict = json.load(db)
    print(json.dumps(dict, indent =4, sort_keys=True))
```

The program I intended to write is getting input and write it to a json file. 
I think I'm a little bit confused about how a json file needs to be written.
from cat the p17.json :

{"foods": ["toilet paper", "pizza"], "counter": 1, "name": "daniel"}{"foods": ["toilet paper", "pizza"], "counter": 2, "name": "mishel"}{"foods": ["toilet paper", "pizza"], "counter": 3, "name": "viktor"}

seems like there are three seperate dictionaries. How do I write to a new json file correctly ?

**UPDATE :**

```
import json

def write_json(data, filename):
    with open(filename,'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

database = '/home/wahalez/dev/python/p17.json'
counter = 1
write = True

write_json({'invites':[]},database) # Initializes the json file

with open(database) as db:
    data = json.load(db)
    print(data)
    temp = data['invites']

    while write:
        invitation = input('Invite :')
        if invitation == 'q':
            write = False
            continue # break from the loop
        temp.append({"name":invitation,"key": counter})
        counter += 1
    write_json(temp,database)


#print the resulting json file
with open(database) as db:
    data = json.load(db)
    print(data)
```

I updated the code to work normally. but when I look at the json file, it seems like the invites key disappeared :

```
wahalez@wahalez:~/dev/python$ cat p17.json ;echo
[
    {
        "name": "daniel",
        "key": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "mishel",
        "key": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "yakov",
        "key": 3
    }
]
```

Comment: [Don't use Python 2](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: Have a look [at this article](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json) describing how to read/write JSON files.

Comment: @pasbi why not ?

Comment: @S3DEV I looked at it, but how do I write multiple dictionaries like I did ?

Comment: It's dead. See the link. [Here's another one](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). Searching the internet will yield a ton of articles. A good reason to use Python 2.x would be using 3rd party code incompatible with modern Python. But if you're just about to learn it: go with Python 3 and save the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the behavior you've described (I get a `ValueError` on Python2 or `JSONDecodeError` on Python 3 when parsing the JSON-file).

But I think I know the problem:
You're writing multiple JSON-objects to a single file.
That's at least unusual, I think it's not allowed (I can't find a reference on the quick, but the parse-error is a strong indicator).

Solution: write an array of objects into the file:

```
data = []
while write:
    name = raw_input("Please enter name :")
    if name == 'q':
        write = False
        continue
    mydict = {
        "counter": counter,
        "name": name,
        "foods": ["toilet paper", "pizza"]
    }
    data.append(mydict)
    json.dump(mydict, db)
    counter +=1

with open(database,'w') as db:
  json.dump(data, db)
```

The code should give you the idea. I haven't tested it.

I strongly recommend using Python 3 and to avoid variables named `dict`.

Comment: Thank you @pasbi, I've updated the code and it seems to work with your solution. But I came up with a problem I showed above. updated the question. I think I know why, it happens because when I write after the while loop again to the file, it overwrites it. But how do I append values to the file then ?

Comment: Yeah, but now you have other problems in the code. I won't update my answer as I don't want to end up in a (edit question, edit answer)-loop. I recommend you to learn what `open` does. I'm leaving.